# Microsoft exchange mail service user login logs

Tags: email, logging, exchange-server

I wonder how can i enable authorization logs for successful and failed logins and than how to see/export them.

Im running Microsoft exchange mail service 2013.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get logs for successful and failed logins, you can do this using MS Logparser to extract the relevant information from your IIS logs.

Download MS Log Parser 2.2 and install - download from:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659

Grab your log files from `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1`, copy them to `C:\log\` and merge them into one big log file using：

```
logparser.exe -i:iisw3c “select * into c:\log\mergedlog\merge.log from c:\log\*” -o:csv
```

Get OWA logins using：

```
LogParser -i:csv “SELECT cs-username, date, time, c-ip, cs-uri-stem, cs(User-Agent) FROM C:\log\mergedlog\merge.log TO C:\log\Output.csv WHERE cs-method LIKE ‘%get%’ and cs-uri-stem LIKE ‘%owa%’
```

Reference:

[Find out if user logged in to OWA / read his emails](https://serverfault.com/questions/558215/find-out-if-user-logged-in-to-owa-read-his-emails)

Comment: I am doing this, but when I enter the second code snippet, I get the error: `Error: Syntax Error: <term2>: no valid LIKE mask`

Comment: Problem solved, somehow I accidently replaced `'` with `\``